# Single Sign On for Jasper Server with Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, jasperserver

I'm setting up Single Sign On for Jaspersoft Server to work with Azure AD. I found in the Azure Market we have jasper server supported
https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/aad.jasperserver?tab=Overview

but I can't find any relate document in anywhere. I think my approach may not correct.

Any advise is really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. Please considering adding code snippets of what you tried. This may lead to more responses.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you want to achieve? Or share some sample to get into your problem.

Comment: Hey Don, thanks for your question, I'm going to take a look into this and see if I can get an official response as to if there's any documentation in regards to this Microsoft side. It might be something that Jasper Server has to configure on their side and it might not be setup yet, in which case you may need to reach out to JasperServer for more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did some research to find the fastest way to integrate between Jasperserver and Azure. I saw Jasper support SSO for CAS but not what I want. I try with spring but still don't know the right way to do yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app today can be used with Azure AD for password based SSO. 
This doc talks about password SSO. If Jaspersoft supports SCIM, AAD can do provisioning to them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-sign-in-problem-password-sso-gallery#configure-the-application-for-password-single-sign-on

Comment: Thanks Frank, I will try to see if Jasper support SCIM, AAD and let you know.

Comment: I don't see Jasper support for SCIM, ADD. Do you have any suggestion Frank?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately if Jasper doesn't support SCIM there isn't much that is possible to move forward. If Jasper is uninterested in being able to be integrate into Azure AD, there isn't much we can do. They can create an app that works with their code and list it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-app-gallery-listing
However it looks like Jasper is not a supported scenario if it doesn't support SCIM,
As we've answered your question, please remember to mark this as answer by clicking the check mark under in the answer section.

Comment: Hi Frank, Can we use Password based SSO in this case? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on#password-based-sso